# Can't initialize char array to a variable in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, initialization, bgi

While using Turbo c++ initializing array of char variable getting error code as follows

```
int gd=DETECT,gm,i,d=0,x,y;
char s[12]={"3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","\0"};
initgraph(&gd,&gm,"..\\BGI");
```

but while used to initialize `s[12][3]`, the initializer list works fine!

Comment: Yes, so? `{"3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","\0"};` is not an array of characters. What else did you expect to happen? Also FYI, Microsoft DOS has no future, get a modern compiler.

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: Bathsheba it was c program in turbo c++. solved the problem. Thanks to everyone

Comment: A bit of pub quiz trivia: `'3'` & c. are `int` types in C, and `char` types in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between `"3"` and `'3'`.

- `"3"` is a string literal
- `'3'` is a character constant *(to nitpick: integer character constant)*

here, to initialize an array of `char` type, you seem to need (brace-enclosed) list of character constants, not strings.

> *but while using s[12][3] works fine*

Well, there you're initializing *arrays*.

*Moral of the story: When in doubt, check the data types!!*

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to store `char`s, not strings, so why do you use double quotes?

`"a"` is a string, `'a'` is a character.

What you actually want to store is strings, and for that you need a 2D array, like this:

```
s[12][3] = {"3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2"};
```

You cannot express 10 as a single character, I mean `'10'` does not exist. Single characters are from 0 to 9 when it comes to digits. For that reason, you need a string for 10, like this `"10"`.

Now, you need the second dimension of your array to be 3, because the string `"10"` (for example) is a null-terminated string, thus 2 characters for its actual contents, plus one for the null-terminator, gives as 3.

---

PS: Turbo-C++ is an ancient compiler. Upgrade to GCC or anything else, really.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change:

```
char s[12]={"3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","1","2","\0"};
```

to

```
char s[13]={'3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','1','2','\0'};
```

As char array elements should be char literals not string literals